# Memory and speed issues relating to reading large files in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, memory

I want to read a file that contains atleast `60k` words. Now I want to `search` if the word that is stored in a variable exist in this file or not.

Ignore the coding, I want to know the `memory issues` related to this problem. If I store all these words in the array and then compare them. The `speed issue` that will effect the `iphone`. If anyone has better way to do it without using `memory and cpu`. Kindly give me details.

Best Regards

Comment: Of course there is Core Data. It will search really fast, but it will certainly effect memory.

Comment: *…better way to do it without using memory and cpu* -- you can always write it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you have is a list of words, the fastest you will probably get is to sort the file, then mmap it.  You can do a binary search on the mapped memory which would be pretty quick.

The nice thing is that you can mmap it read-only, and it will not result in any dirty memory pages, which is really what you have to worry about when talking about memory usage on an iOS device.